# What's the correct mapconfig.xml to import railways with osm2pgrouting

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgrouting

I am trying to create a railway router using pgRouting with OSM data.

My aim is to do it on the planet scale but I've been having some issues so I am trying to solve these issues on a smaller data set first.

I've downloaded the data from [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) with this query:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“railway=rail”
*/
[out:xml][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  way["railway"="rail"]({{bbox}});
  <;
  >;
);
// print results
out body;
```

Then I import the data into postGIS using osm2pgrouting, which runs without errors.

```
osm2pgrouting --dbname pgr_routing --file test-rail.osm --username pgr_routing --tags --attributes --clean -p 5438 --password hunter2 --conf mapconfig.xml
```

And my mapconfig.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <tag_name name="railway" id="1">
    <tag_value name="rail" id="100"/>
    <tag_value name="subway" id="101"/>
    <tag_value name="light_rail" id="102"/>
    <tag_value name="tram" id="103"/>
    <tag_value name="narrow_gauge" id="104"/>
    <tag_value name="monorail" id="105"/>
  </tag_name>
</configuration>
```

However, in postGIS, there are many missing segments. My best guess is that my `mapconfig.xml` file is wrong but I'm not sure.

Here's an example of missing segments from pgAdmin interface:
[image]

This is how it looks like on overpass-turbo interface:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

That config file looks fine to me.

I'd say this is simply an export issue: i.e. *overpass-turbo* does not keep references between nodes and ways recursively by default - you'd need to explicitly tell it to [like so](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1jih):

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“railway=*”
*/
[out:xml][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “railway=*”
  way["railway"]({{bbox}});
  <;    // recusive up
  >;    // recusive down
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I suggest to **try on a small, *verified* OSM extract** (from e.g. [GeoFabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html)) instead.

---

**However:**

Make sure you understand (and are prepared for) that *osm2pgrouting*

1. expects the **uncompressed XML format** to work on - there's precise numbers on the *OSM Wiki* somewhere I believe, but expect `europe-latest.osm.pbf` alone (25GB) to **decompress into ~*700GB* of OSM XML data**
2. needs to parse **at least *all nodes* into memory** (unfortunately a necessary step when working with OSM data) - and will rather ungracefully error out printing `Killed` when running OOM (the 277MB `centro-latest.osm.pbf` - 6.2GB decompresed OSM XML - does not fit into 16GB of RAM)

Two things you could do:

- use an OSM tool of your choice (I prefer [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/)) to remove **all end every bit** of irrelevant `nodes|ways|relations` and unused meta data/tags from the export *prior to running any means of import*
- use a different tool and import pipeline - I am using a custom rewrite of a very fast and dead simple little tool called [osm4routing2](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing2), and while I cannot open source mine, I would always use that tool over any other out there; it creates an `edge` and `nodes` file based topology, and you'd simply `COPY` both CSVs into PostgreSQL. However, you'd need to change the [hard-coded](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing2/blob/main/src/osm4routing/categorize.rs) tag extraction for this to work on railways.